# Joomla nBill user / client name query

Tags: sql, joomla, inner-join

I'm attempting to do a rather complex SQL query, it's getting way out of my league, I think I'm close on this, my forehead hurts now, I toss my hands up and ask for an assist.

```
<?php       
                                $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
                                $userid = "SELECT * FROM #__users  WHERE id='".$row->userid."' ";           
                                $db->setQuery
                                ("
                                select #__nbill_contact.user_id as userid, concat(#__nbill_entity.company_name, ' - ', #__nbill_contact.first_name, ' ',        
                                #__nbill_contact.last_name) as contact_entity from #__nbill_entity 
                                INNER JOIN  #__nbill_entity_contact on  #__nbill_entity.id = #__nbill_entity_contact.entity_id 
                                INNER JOIN  #__nbill_contact on #__nbill_entity_contact.contact_id = #__nbill_contact.id and #__nbill_contact.user_id > 0"
                                );
                                $user_type_detail = $db->loadAssoc();
                                ech $user_tpe_detail["contact_entity"]
                            ;?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you trying to do here ? little explanation would be nice

Comment: I am attempting to echo out the "Company Name" represented by the "contact_entity" column, based on the logged in user.

Comment: Some db schema and desired output would also be nice.

Comment: So I've got a logged in user, from the joomla user table "userid"
and I've got an nbill client entity_contact table that holds the joomla userid as "user_id"
and there's an entity id column in the entity_contact table that refers back to the entity table where im attempting to echo out the "company_name" column